# Difference between git pull . master vs git merge master

Tags: git, git-merge

Having no remote repository, just one local repository with two branches.

```
$ git branch -a
  master
* devel
```

Are following commands **in this context** the same/synonym?

```
$ git pull . master
```

and

```
$ git merge master
```

**UPDATE:**

`$ git help pull` gives following information

```
SYNOPSIS
   git pull <options> <repository> <refspec>...

DESCRIPTION
   ...
   Note that you can use . (current directory) as the <repository> to pull
   from the local repository — this is useful when merging local branches
   into the current branch.
```

I actually don't understand why this is useful as mentioned in this manpage.

Comment: no git-merge - Join two or more development histories together. And git-pull - Fetch from and merge with another repository or a local branch

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git pull . master` fetches from the current repository (a no-op) and will then do something to bring the current branch up to date with `master`. That something might be a merge but it might also be a rebase depending on the configuration setting `pull.rebase` or `branch.master.rebase`.

In the case of a merge, the merge strategy my be affected by `pull.twohead`.

`git merge master` will always merge master with the default merge strategy.

Answer (score 21):

`pull` is a combination command, `fetch` followed by `merge`. With default or sensible params it will synchronize your current branch.

With the params as in question most of its work is sabotaged. the fetch part is overruled to use the current repo, so that is skipped, and you explicitly ask master overruling FETCH_HEAD.

So in that form I believe they are identical (and I'd put the first in nonsense category too).

Comment: It'll be the same either way since the remote is '.', no?

Comment: as I pointed out there is no remote repository. so `fetch` is not doing anything. Can you adjust your answer; I am happy with mentioning that usually git pull is equivalent to git fetch & git merge.

Answer (score 5):

the only difference - in second case (`git merge master`) it will merge with not *fresh* data, but with data from your last remote update. So, if you just have made `fetch` (or `git remote update`) - they work the same way, but if you updated local repository a long time ago - it will merge with old snapshot.

Not sure the period in `git pull . master` is a correct syntaxes...

Comment: it left me baffled too, but appears to work skipping the fetch part