# Git Merge - Difference between pull and merge

Tags: git, git-pull

In my `.gitconfig` I have `rebase` set as default pull option. I am trying to understand what's the difference between

`git merge origin/develop`

vs.

`git pull origin develop`

All I currently understand is `git pull origin develop` pulls the branch `develop` from `origin` (remote) into current branch. But so does `git merge origin/develop` (or, does it)?

Thanks,

Comment: Already answers  https://stackoverflow.com/q/17339091/9491394

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between git merge origin/master and git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756614/difference-between-git-merge-origin-master-and-git-pull)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+%22git+pull%22+%22git+merge%22

Answer (score 7, accepted):

git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch.

The command

```
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

is really just the same as

```
git fetch <remote>
git merge <remote>/<branch>
```

So there is no practical difference between

```
git pull origin master
```

and

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

In order to understand more check this documentation [Pull and Merge](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)

Comment: So there is no difference if I do either way. That's all I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference here is the difference between how rebase works and how merge works.

Rebase will rewind to the shared point between the branches and it will replay the commit one by one on top of the head. (not introducing and new merge commits)

Merge will take the lump sum of the branch and merge it on top producing 1 new merge commit with the entire goodies in there.

Rebase is "better" as it preserves the history in a cleaner way.

You can also try a `git merge BRANCH --ff-only`

This is similar to rebase as it will just replay the commits on top preserving the history.